# unable to retrieve the latest row based on a date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine the following 3 tables:

train: key, name, departure_date
group_train: train, group
group: key, name

The group_train.train as a foreign key relation with train.key and group_train.group with group.key.

A group can contain multiple trains and a train might be present in multiple groups.

I would like to retrieve the latest train to departure by group. Based on the train.departure_date

I already tried multiple types of joins, sub queries and group by clauses. All of them without success. I seems a straightforward query but for some reason I got stuck!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle? Getting the latest per group is different in each DB.

Comment: I am currently using oracle.

Comment: When you were writing the question, didn't you see a big box saying that SQL questions should be tagged with the database? Why didn't you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytical function Approach;

```
SELECT train.*
FROM
    (
     SELECT T.KEY,
            T.NAME AS TRAIN_NAME,
            T.departure_date,
            G.name AS GROUP_NAME,
            RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY G.group ORDER BY T.departure_date DESC) AS MY_RANK
     FROM GROUP_TRAIN GT
      INNER JOIN TRAIN T ON (GT.TRAIN = T.KEY)
      INNER JOIN GROUP G ON (GT.group = G.group)
   ) train
WHERE MY_RANK   = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try joining all three tables and fetch one latest row output of it like:

```
SELECT g.key, g.name, MAX(t.departure_date)
FROM train t INNER JOIN group_train gt ON t.key = gt.train
INNER JOIN group g ON gt.group = g.key
GROUP by g.key, g.name
ORDER BY t.departure_date DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't get the latest per group, it just gets the latest of all.

Comment: Sorry i didn't read properly about OP needs to group by key. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT g.key, g.name, t.key, t.name, t.departure_date
FROM group g 
INNER JOIN group_train gt ON g.key = gt.group
INNER JOIN train t ON gt.train = t.key 
INNER JOIN (SELECT gt.group, MAX(t.departure_date) AS departure_date
            FROM group_train gt 
            INNER JOIN train t ON gt.train = t.name 
            GROUP BY gt.group
           ) AS A ON g.key = gt.group AND t.departure_date = A.departure_date;
```